# About the first Sylow theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

The first Sylow theorem states the existence of $p$-subgroups. I was wondering if there can be other subgroups of the same order and different structure.

Let's take a big group which has a $2^2$ factor in its order. The theorem guarantees it will have at least one $2$-subgroup of order $4$.
Let's assume, thanks to the third Sylow theorem, we find $N$ of these subgroups, which turn to be Klein $4$ groups. Now the second Sylow theorem is telling us they will be all Klein $4$ groups since they are conjugated.

The question is: can this group contain other subgroups of order $4$ with a different structure, like $C_4$ for instance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

Say, let $G$ be a finite group and let $p$ be a prime factor of $n=|G|$ and let $k$ be the highest power of $p$ dividing $n$. Then for all $i=1,2,\ldots, k$ there will be subgroups of $G$ order $p^i$, including for $i=k$. Those don't need to be isomorphic. Say, in $G=S_4$ (the group of permutations of the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$) you can have a subgroup of order $4$ generated by the cycle $(1 2 3 4)$ (isomorphic to $C_4$) and another subgroup of order $4$ generated by two cycles $(1 2)$ and $(3 4)$ (which is isomorphic to Klein group).

However, for the special case $i=k$: any two subgroups of order $p^k$ are conjugated - hence isomorphic. To continue with the previous example: as $|S_4|=4!=24=2^3\cdot 3$, any two subgroups of order $2^3=8$ in it are necessarily isomorphic to each other.

Comment: So in D8 we have both C4 and V4 and they don't need to be isomorphic. So the answer Is Yes in that case. Similarly for $S_4$ as you explained above.

Comment: However the third Sylow thm Will not help us in finding the Number of those 2classes of 4 order subgroups

Comment: Correct. And also being of order $16$ it has non-isomorphic subgroups $C_8$ and $D_4$. Of order $16$,of course, there is only one subgroup (the group itself). However the statement applies even for groups with multiple prime divisors of their order - only the "largest" $p$-groups (which we call *Sylow* $p$-groups) are all conjugated/isomorphic to each other.

Comment: May or may not help. If, for example, you determine that there must be *one single* maximal (Sylow) $p$-group, and if you can discern its structure, then all the smaller $p$-groups are contained in it - and so you may be able to tell (knowing the structure of the Sylow $p$-group) how many of *those* there are. The same thing applies if there are multiple Sylow $p$-groups but you can tell (from the conditions of the problem you're solving) something about their intersections. E.g. if the intersections must for some reason be trivial.

Comment: Not sure about the group of order 16...I meant D8 made by 8 elements, in my case. However I got what you meant. Not Always Easy to understand where to use the $D_n$ or $D_2n$ convention.

Comment: Ah, ok... May be that some people call $D_8$ the dihedral group of $8$ elements. This is not the convention I've used (and apparently not the one [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) is using either: "$D_n$ or $\text{Dih}_n$ refers to the symmetries of the $n$-gon, a group of order $2n$...").

Comment: I've read geometers are used to $D_n$, while pure group theorist are using $D_2n$, to highlight the order in the naming

Answer (score 4):

The wording of your question is a little murky. If $2^2$ is the largest power of $2$ dividing the order of your group, then "No" - if one subgroup of order 4 is a Klein 4-group, then all must be since subgroups of order 4 here are Sylow 2-subgroups and thus all isomorphic. On the other hand, consider $G=C_2 \times C_2 \times C_4$ (the direct product of two cyclic groups of order 2 and a cyclic group of order 4). In this case $G$ is its own (unique) Sylow 2-subgroup. Also, $G$ contains a subgroup with Klein 4-group structure and a subgroup with cyclic (order 4) structure.

What can be said in general? If finite group $G$ contains a subgroup $H$ of prime power order (say $p^k$), then every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ must itself have a subgroup isomorphic to $H$.

So if you have a finite group with subgroups isomorphic to both $C_2 \times C_2$ and $C_4$, then that group must have Sylow 2-subgroups large enough to accommodate both of these structures. For example, the dihedral group of order 8 is such a group.

Comment: So in D8 both C4 and V4 Will be 2-subgroups of order 4? But the second thm would claim they should be all conjugated...so the answer would be Yes in that case

Comment: Ah no, since only the 2-subgroups of order 8 should be in that case